# Eclipse configuration "Execution Environments"

Tags: eclipse, java-8

My Eclipse installs won't detect a compatible JRE.

I downloaded a fresh version of eclipse(Mars1,2 & Neon). I selected the Java EE developer install. Then I installed.  Now before creataing a project or doing anything before the default install if I go to "Window > Prefrences > java > Installed JREs > Execution Environment"  None of my Execution Environments contain any Compatible JREs. 
[image]

I'm not new to eclipse. I know I can set project specific settings to get my projects to compile. I can tell maven to use a specific JRE. I can tell tomcat to run on a specific JRE.  But to get the Maven, Tomcat, and TestNG plugins to play together correctly in eclipse it seems to need this configuration to be set up right. Else you get maven resetting your JRE every time you make a settings change, or tomcat telling you you can't run with the 1.8 project facet, etc.  All kinds of problems.

I've got my Java_home environment variable set to -  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74

I've got %JAVA_HOME%\bin in my path.

I can run java --version and get the version.

and I've told eclipse to use this JDK as the installed JRE 
[image]

I think the most frustrating thing is that I've set this up on my home computer and things work just fine. I'm wondering if anyone has an idea why eclipse wouldn't recognize an installed JRE as compatible.  Or if anyone knows how to force eclipse to recognize a JRE as compatible. I've done plenty of searching on the topic already and nothing has worked including trying to make my own .ee file in the JDK directory.  I appreciate any help or insight.  Thanks.

Comment: You must click on an entry in the 'Execution Environments' list to see the compatible JREs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying random things in desperation I downloaded the "Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2" eclipse plugin from the eclipse market place and it seems to have fixed the problem.

I'm using Mars 2 just to be clear. Which I still don't understand why it doesn't work out the box but since I can move on with my work I'll close this out.

Answer (score 2):

**For me also** there is no compatible JREs displayed **initially**.

**If your first screenshot is correct**, the solution will be fraustrating one.
**If not, kindly ignore this clue**.

**Forgive me** to ask the stupid Question - Did you **clicked** the "Execution Environment" at the left side menu?

Before someone start searching me to beat, I am logging off ;-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but even after selecting a specific one there is nothing.  I've updated the original question to reflect that.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you clicked JavaSE-1.7 and 1.6 too?